# mac ports openssl 1.0.2g disables SSLv2 which is required by mongodb

Tags: macos, mongodb, openssl, macports

Updating openssl to 1.0.2g using mac ports disables the SSLv2 due to CVE-2016-0800

The problem is mongodb built using mac ports requires this SSLv2

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/mongod
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /opt/local/bin/mongod
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

The solution according to [CVE-2016-0800](http://openssl.org/news/secadv/20160301.txt) is to define **enable-ssl2** but even then they mention the following:

```
SSL_CTX_clear_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
```

or

```
SSL_clear_options(ssl, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
```

which I'm not sure if mongodb follows the directive.

- Anyone has a reference for this on a mongodb issue?
- Is there a simple fix on the mongodb code for this?

Comment: *"The problem is mongodb built using mac ports requires this SSLv2..."* - SSLv2 has been broken for 15 or 20 years or so. You don't want to enable it. File a bug report against MongoDB or Macports.

Comment: Someone already did :)
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/50778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongodb @3.2.3_1 solved the issue